# How to access a RUNNING remote desktop

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, vnc

here is my problem:

- I have been working the whole day (on my office computer running Ubuntu) on a text document using a text editor (kile)
- when I came back home, I tried to copy the (newer) version I have been working on all day over the (older) version I have at home (I used winscp for that, my home computer is under Windows). I wanted to continue my work during the weekend
- I made a mistake: I did the exact opposite. So, currently, the versions on both my home and work computer hard drives are the old version
- BUT: the text editor (kile) is still running on my work computer. And the newer version of the document is still in RAM!
- I have access to my work computer, with admin rights, using SSH
- I dumped the memory of the (still running) kile process and managed to recover (sadly) only half of my work
- Is there a way I can access the RUNNING desktop on my work computer using SSH to simply click on kile's "save" button and fix my mistake?
- I cannot physically access my work computer
- I dont know much about remote desktops

Any help would be really appreciated. This is quite urgent work I have to finish before Monday.

Thanks in advance,
VF

Comment: VNC -- you can start vnc server through ssh and then you can connect to it, which should show you your running desktop.

Comment: I just tried that. All I can see is a terminal window. I guess this is because the VNC server I launched is not running in the context of the (already running) desktop. Any idea?

Comment: If you dont have vnc server installed, you can ssh into your office machine and apt-get  vnc4server, and after installed, run 'vncserver -geometry 1920x1080 (or whatever your home desktop is running as resolution). On the windows machine, download tightvncserver. Also, make note of the output that vncserver gives you after you start it, it will give you an output along the lines of  "New ' <servername>'  desktop is <server>:1", this is the name of the computer youre trying to connect to. If all goes well, you'll be  seeing your office desktop!

Comment: I did all you suggested. I started vncserver from ssh. All I can see (in VNC client, I used multivnc) is a terminal window. I mean, a terminal window which is ubuntu-themed. But that's all. I can see kile running with PS -A but it's not visible in VNC. I dont know how to run VNC server in the context of the (already running) desktop.

Comment: in that terminal window (work computer), install vnc4server and activate it on there. On the Home computer side, connect to it with the vnc client.

Comment: I did that too: same result. A new Ubuntu-themed terminal window and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kile creates **.backup** files by default in the same dir. Check for those. If that didn't work, then use a VNC server. SSH into and run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install x11vnc
$ x11vnc -storepasswd #Create a password
$ x11vnc -usepw -display :0 #Run it
```

This will log you into a running session.
Use any Remote Desktop client to connect (I am not sure if the connection will be encrypted, but you only need a few seconds, and can stop the server, so no big deal), and do your thing.

If you get a login error, try the following, but it might restart your session, so be very careful. You have been warned:

```
$ sudo x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -display :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -usepw
```

Comment: @VincentForman no problem. Which was it backup files or VNC?

Comment: VNC did the trick. The .backup of kile were overwritten too (with older versions) when I did my copying mistake. For some reason, vncserver -display :0 was not working. x11vnc -usepw -display :0 (as you suggested) worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach to continue file edits between computers is to park such important files/dirs on Dropbox on both computers.  This offers seamless continuation of work as long as you save changes prior to changing machines.